# nHapi GT1 segment for DFT_P03 returning empty collection

Tags: c#, hl7, hl7-v2, nhapi

I am stumped on the following

Sample message:

```
MSH|^~\&|CWM|MySender|UNKNOWN|UNKNOWN|20160711080000||DFT^P03|976503|P|2.5|
EVN|P03|20160711080000
PID||12345^^^RIS|||Test^Patient||192532325445|F|||27 Lotus street ^^Morningside^^2121|||m7715050|3|S|||23377|||||||||||N
PV1||I||||||999^Ref Doctor^||||||||N||A|160998675|||||||||||||||||||||||||20160701130000
GT1|1||EVERYMAN^ADAM^A||2222 HOME STREET^^ISHPEMING^MI^49849^""^|444-33 3333|555-555-2004||||SEL^SELF|444-33 3333||||AUTO CLINIC|2222 HOME STREET^^ISHPEMING^MI^49849^""|555-555-2004|
OBR|1||2015021000043|20310^CT of the soft tissues of the neck, with contrast^CT^4^CT Scan Machine|0|201502101124|201502101124|||||||||^MIKE^SMITH||||||||IMIL
FT1|1|E292252||201502101124||CG|00279519|F||1|||IMIL|PRIVATE^||||A1|||^MIKE^SMITH^^^||2015021000043^IMIL||20310^CT of the soft tissues of the neck, with contrast^CT^4^CT Scan Machine|CT
PR1|1|AQ|20310^CT of the soft tissues of the neck, with contrast^CT^4^CT Scan Machine||201502101124|D||||||||||CT|
```

I can parse the message, and I can work with the PID no problem, but the GT1 just does not get accepted. DFT does support the GT1 segment (optional) but it is just always returning an empty list

```
PipeParser parser = new PipeParser();
IMessage m = parser.Parse(msg);
DFT_P03 dft = m as DFT_P03;
GT1 gt1 = dft.GetGT1();
var memName = gt1.GetGuarantorName()[0];
```

then the final line blows up saying that my index is out of bounds, i.e. I have nothing in my gt1 collection.

Am I loading it in wrong?

Comment: You mix gt1 and gT1. Note the uppercase T!

Comment: I git excited for a second, but no, it was a copy past error into SO. ill fix the post. The problem still stands :) Thanks anyway

Comment: You could try ..GuarantorName(0).FamilyName.Value

Comment: still comes up null, even tho GT1-3-1 is not null in the message

Comment: Did you check, that the order of your segments is correct and that there is no error when parsing. I think GT1 should come as last segment in your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of segments of your sample message is wrong. GT1-segment comes after the TransactionGroups and the ProcedureGroups.

Comment: Holy smokes you are right. I didnt realise that order was so important. Chameleon and Mirth never seemed to care about this, but yeah, hl7 spec does put it all the way at the, AND it does also list it in the comments as being on the bottom. Wow. Thanks!